# Unsuccessful attempt to change alpha value of pixels of BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, pixel, alpha

The expected output of my code (shown below):

---

> before 255
>   after 0

---

But the actual output is:

---

> before 255
>   after 255

---

I expect the after to be something other than 255,  because I've tried to explicitly set the lower bit of the pixels to 0.  Hoping for analysis of what might not be working.

---

```
File fimin = new File("C:\\sample.png");
BufferedImage img = null;
img = ImageIO.read(fimin);
int width = img.getWidth();
int height = img.getHeight();
int val, alpha;

System.out.println("before" + (((img.getRGB(0, 0)) >> 24) & 0xff)); 

for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        val = 0;
        val = img.getRGB(i, j);
        val &= 0xfeffffff;//set lower bit ofalpha to zero
        img.setRGB(i, j, val);
    }
}
System.out.println("after" + (((img.getRGB(0, 0)) >> 24) & 0xff));
```

Comment: Sometimes, I should not be around computers :}

Comment: What's the point of setting `val` to 0 each time?

Comment: Hi Sai, to help out @gpasch for helping if his answer helps you, please click the up arrow to 'upvote' his answer,  and click the √ next to it to show it's the 'accepted answer' (the answer that works for you), and if you think my contribution was good, please upvote my answer as well. That's how this site works, to help each other advance and make progress.

Answer (score 2):

The read image is not of type ARGB.

To make sure you have an image of type ARGB do this:

```
  BufferedImage b2=new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
  b2.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
```

Now you can change the alpha:

```
    System.out.println("before"+(((b2.getRGB(0,0))>>24)&0xff)+" "+img.getType()+" "+BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB+" "+BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    int val=b2.getRGB(0, 0);
    val&=0xfeffffff;//set lower bit ofalpha to zero
    b2.setRGB(0, 0, val);
    System.out.println("after"+(((b2.getRGB(0,0))>>24)&0xff));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, and used a png, and it worked as expected:

- before: 255
- after: 254

Maybe the image I was using had the pixel bytes in the expected order, ARGB, whereas the image file you loaded didn't? If that's true, [@gpasch's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41542033/2079103) answer will probably let your code handle more image formats (e.g. lets you control the image's representation in memory).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class image {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java image <image filepath>\n");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        File imageFilename = new File(args[0]);

        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(imageFilename);
        } catch (Exception c) {
            System.out.println("Error reading image file " + imageFilename);
        }

        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();
        int val, alpha;

        System.out.println("Lower byte before: " + (((img.getRGB(0, 0)) >> 24) & 0xff));

        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                val = img.getRGB(i, j);
                val &= 0xfeffffff;//set lower bit ofalpha to zero 
                img.setRGB(i, j, val);
           }       
        }       
        System.out.println("Lower byte after: " + (((img.getRGB(0, 0)) >> 24) & 0xff));
    }
}
```